# how to set language preference in URL in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Define route this way? Can anyone tell me how it will be used if i have to lang option on

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { lang = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Home", action = "Index", identifier = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

MVC will strictly pattern-match, whether you said that the lang-Parameter is optional or not:

a/b/c/d

=> lang = a, controller = b, action = c, id = d.

a/b/c

=> lang = a, controller = b, action = c, id = null (because the default value says this is optional)

a/b

=> lang = a, controller = b, action = Index (because of the default value), id = null

etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what are you use

For routing you can use:
Sammy.Js + Knockout

Or Angular - Angular had nice routing